# User JSON.parse() in ApiService.ts in angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

I write code for api call apiCall.sevice.ts in that I use JSON.parse() but it not woirking.

I used JSON.parse(sessionStorage.usertoken); for get value from session and sent to API headers in apiCall.service.ts
But it gives me an error like 
core.js:12501 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

so what we can do for getting value from a session in service.ts.

After Login

```
   if (this.resp.data.agentType === 'Admin')
      {
        sessionStorage.userdesg = JSON.stringify(this.resp.data);
        sessionStorage.usertoken = JSON.stringify(this.resp.token);
      }
```

I can save usertoken in session and for send API this token fetch from me

```
    path = 'https://example.com/';
    secret_key: string = 'absbsnsb124';
    merchant_abc_access_token = "nmsndsm89890";
    merchant_access_token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.usertoken);

   httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'merchant-access-secret-key': this.secret_key,
      'merchant-access-token': this.merchant_access_token ,
      'merchant-abc-access-token': this.merchant_abc_access_token 
      })
     };
```

It gives me an error.

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

can you please help in i user angular 7

Comment: it looks like you are trying to parse something that isnt json

Comment: json is invalid....  try to validate it with some online json validator

Comment: Inspect or print the value of `sessionStorage.usertoken` in browser console. The value seems to be invalid string which can not be parsed to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Your `this.resp.token` is returning `undefined`.

The consequence of this is that `JSON.stringify(undefined)` returns `undefined` and setting `sessionStorage.key = undefined;` stores it as `"undefined"`.

When you retrive the value, `JSON.parse("undefined")` throws the follwing error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: I think the answer is incorrect, I don't understand the reason of -1